# React Native fetch POST variables not received on server

Tags: react-native, post, fetch

I have tried different ways with **fetch** or **axios** to POST to my server but it seems that the post body turns empty . My initial code is this.
So the connection to the server is good. I have configured server to respond with **$_POST** variables received but the $_POST return empty. This happens when I use **JSON.stringify** on  **body**. I have also tried with **FormData** and it works fine but only on **iOS**. On my **Android** device and emulator I get **Possible Unhandled Promise: Network request failed** error (both https and http).
And I want to make it work on both iOS and Android. So till now I have manage to send post with formData only on iOS.

Any Solutions that works on Android and iOS?

```
import FormData from "FormData";

export const login = (emailUsername, password) => {
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("emailUsername", emailUsername);
  formData.append("password", password);

  return async dispatch => {
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://myserver.net/api/app/auth.php",
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            emailUsername:emailUsername,
            password:password
        })
      }
    );

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error("Something went wrong!");
    }

    const resData = await response.json();
    console.log(resData);
  };
};
```

Comment: Have you tried using something like Postman to make sure your server isn't misconfigured and isn't stripping the `POST` body somehow? I know that can sometimes happen with `301` redirects for `https`, for example.

Comment: I have tested server, It works fine no errors on server. Like I said. I have manage to send post with body:FormData only on iOS so it worked and I know that this code should work fine as it is for both devices but it doesn't.

Comment: FormData is the way to go unless you prefer to change the backend, the point is that with the request you shared PHP doesn't fill your post data in `$_POST`. If you wanted to get it you would have to do something like: `$post_data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));`. Show us your FormData attempt, it should work on Android too

Comment: Thanks @bug . Your solution worked. I still don't understand why they are not received in $_POST or $_REQUEST variables.

Comment: No problem, the reason is that `$_POST` is meant to store form data, what you are sending is JSON, they are two different formats, have a look [here](https://www.smtpeter.com/en/documentation/json-vs-post) to see how the two requests look like

Comment: I understand now. Thanks allot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @bug I have find a solution. I was expecting to receive POST content to my $_POST or $_REQUEST variables on my server, but instead I had to get them this way.

`$post_data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));`